# FFmpeg not decreasing

Tags: ffmpeg

I need `ffmpeg` to transform a video stream into images and reduce their size only if they don't fit in a 1000x1000 box.

My issue is that if the image is smaller, ffmpeg increases the size of the image to 1000 in width or height, whereas I don't want small images to be upscaled. The `force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease` does not seem to work here. Any ideas why?

Here is my shell command:

```
ffmpeg -i 'rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov' -r 5 -vf scale=w=1000:h=1000:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -f image2 -qscale:v 1 ./output_%01d.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following scale expression,

```
scale=`if(lte(iw,1000)*lte(ih,1000),iw,iw*1000/max(iw,ih)):if(lte(iw,1000)*lte(ih,1000),ih,ih*1000/max(iw,ih))`
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mathematical expression for more complex scaling rules, try following: `-vf scale=w='min(iw,1000)':h=-2`